Notes lagging severely after iOS 18 and macOS Sequoia update
I have some big notes, using colored text and titles.
On every device (iPhone 16 Pro, iPad, Mac with Apple silicon) they lag badly while scrolling (especially when using collapsible headings.)
Does this seem to be a bad software optimization?
Apple Discussion: Notes App lagging after iOS 18 Update

You might want to file a bug report with Apple. iPhone, macOS. The Apple Discussion you linked to shows many folks have this problem.

it was present on 18, 18.1 and 18.2

Hopefully you can break the presumed malfunctioning iCloud sync loop between the devices without needing to file a bug report. See my answer to get normal support to assist

I have seen issues with iCloud sync cause this. I also can’t reproduce it, notes is as fast on complicated items as it was for the past several years after this fall’s OS updates.
My hunch is it’s more of a general issue than the notes app needing to be optimized, but let’s try and isolate the issue for you and anyone else in this situation.

First put the devices that sync notes in airplane mode and then restart with them all, let then start up not connected to the internet.
Open notes app and repeat your performance test on the Mac, ideally with zero apps starting on reboot and immediately after you have the issue, open activity monitor, select notes app and run sysdiagnose so you can report the specific, reproducible issue to engineering for assistance in either an iCloud sync issue or a notes database issue.
Notes database issue, easy for them to help when you can reproduce it in airplane mode on the Mac.
iCloud sync, they have profiles to load and discover what exactly is broken with enhanced logging.
Either way, you have a performance issue that they can get to the bottom of this for you (with some moderate effort gathering logs and troubleshooting) and perhaps fix an edge case for everyone.
Sorry to put more work on you, but this one is going to be solvable in my experience with a little more troubleshooting.
Start with the Mac, as it’s most accessible for diagnostics and fixing the issue with help from support if needed, then you can do similar changes on the other devices if needed.
